# npm jquery, which is the correct one to support older browsers

Tags: jquery, npm, browserify

I want to use browserify on a existing website. The website uses jQuery 1.10.*, so I went out searching for jquery 1x in npm, but only found jquery 2.1.1. I guess I could use this together with the migrate plugin, but I haven't found that as a separate module, only bundled with a version 2.0.0b2 (jquery-with-migrate). I also have seen a jquery-browserify module, so now I am a bit confused on how suport older browsers using jquery from npm.. Am I missing something really obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little hunting it looks like you can specify the package version number by using `package@version` in the `npm` command, e.g.:

```
npm install jquery@1.10.2
```